# store data in mysql using sails.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I'm new in sails.js NodeJs framework.Actually I am building a simple registration and login form.I would like to save the users details in mysql database.

Here is my UserController.js file:

```
module.exports = {

'registration': function(req,res){

    res.view();
},

create: function(req,res,next){

    user.create(req.params.all(), function userCreated(err,user){

        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        else{


        }

    });
 }
 }
```

User.js Model file model:

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
    name:{
    type: 'string',
    required: true
},

title:{

    type: 'string',

    required: true
},

email:{

    type: 'string',

    email: true,

    required: true,

    unique: true
},
encryptedPassword:{

    type: 'string',

    required: true
}
}
};
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Actually i have a user controller and a user model.I dont want to use RESTFULL JSON API.i want to get all the data from the form and save them in mysql data base.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your controller so registration is without quotes. Also change `user.create(req.params.all(), function userCreated(err,user){` to `User.create(req.params.all(), function userCreated(err,user){` (e.g. capitalize the U in user).

Next, create a folder under views named `user`.  Create a file called registration.ejs with a form like this:

```
<form action='/user/create' method='POST'>

  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="your name" name="name">
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="your title" name="title">
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="your email address" name="email">
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="password" name="password">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Create Account"/>

</form>
```

**Added Connection Configuration**

Open `/config/connections.js` and change the default settings to something like:

```
someMysqlServer: {
adapter: 'sails-mysql',
host: 'localhost',
user: '<put username here>',
password: '<put password here>',
database: '<put database here>'
}
```

Finally, go to `/config/models.js` and place insert this into it:

`connection: 'someMysqlServer',`

Next time you start the server, the data will be saved in your mysql db.  Make sure you've created a database with the same name as you gave in the connection config :)

Comment: thanks. please can you show me the code for the UserController on how to get details from the forms and save them in MySql database i created. i don't wanna use the default "computer disk" as a coonection

Answer (score 0):

Main code of controller

```
create: function (req, res) {
        var payload = {
          name:req.body.name,
          price:req.body.price,
          category:req.body.category,
          author:req.body.author,
          description:req.body.description
        };
       Book.create(payload).exec(function(err){
          if(err){
            res.status(500).json({'error':'something is not right'})
          }else{
            res.status(200).json({'success':true, 'result':payload, 'message':'Book Created success'})
          }
       });
   },
```